# dbml with connectionstring

Tags: linq-to-sql

how to generate a DBML file using the ConnectionString in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) (a free download from MS)

It is not really "in" ASP.NET MVC that you do this.

Kindness,

Dan